# Calc function doesn't work for exponentiation

Tags: css

The question is very short:

For some reason, `calc()` function doesn't work in my case.

```
<style>
body {
    padding-left: calc(1% * 1%);
}
</style>
```

Chrome says it isn't valid value. Why?

(Is there another way to use [exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation), which is based on element width, with `calc()`?)

Comment: no there is no way to use exponentiation using calc()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As covered [in the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), when using multiplication in `calc()`, at least one of the values has to be a [number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/number): either an integer or a floating point number, but unitless.

This means these are valid values:

```css
calc(1% * 2);
calc(3 * 10px);
```

And these are not:

```css
calc(1% * 1%);
calc(10px * 10px);
```

Comment: It seems I should accept this answer. But is there another way to use [exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation) with `calc`?

Comment: As per MDN, currently there are just 4 operators (`+ - * /`) so you would need to a different approach depending on specific thing that you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @johnc.j. It would be good to make a separate question for that, possibly with a backlink to this one. However off the top of my head I don't know of a way unless you introduce some additional DOM.

Answer (score 0):

`*`

In Multiplication. At least one of the arguments must be a Number

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Both are percents not a number. You could add them instead.

```
.box {
    padding-left: calc(15% + 10%);
}
```